# how can I add to groupings in group_by_at dplyr function

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, grouping, tidyverse

Trying to add a grouping to an tibble that has an existing grouping using dplyr, but the 'add' in group_by_at() doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone have any ideas why?

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(letters,100,replace = T),
                 col2 = sample(letters,100,replace = T),
                 col3 = sample(letters,100,replace = T))

# group_by_at add doesn't work as desired:
df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  group_by_at('col2', add = T) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) 

# but group_by add does work as desired:
df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  group_by(col2, add = T) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need `.add` instead of `add` as the `Usage` suggested in `?group_by_at` is

> group_by_at(.tbl, .vars, .funs = list(), ..., .add = FALSE,
>     .drop = group_drops(.tbl))

```
df %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
   group_by_at('col2', .add = TRUE) %>%
   summarise(n = n())
```

NOTE: After the `summarise` step, one of the grouping variables are removed especially the last grouping variable

Comment: great! Fastest answer ever. Do you know why it is .add instead of add?

Comment: can't accept as correct answer for 10 more minutes, but will do!

Comment: @DomBurns  Thanks. I think it is described (in general) in vignettes.  Couldn't find it now.  I will post it here if I find a link